# react native/JS nested array detect

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I have a nested array here i have some answers under a question 300.
Here some answers has reply also. Like **"parent_answer_id"**

Here in my application I am trying to display only if **"parent_answer_id" == 0** it will display in list and if others item's **"parent_answer_id" match** with other item "id" then there will display extra content "**more reply >**" on that loop.

So far I tried in react native:

```
var k =0;
for ( let j = 0; j < Object.keys(item.answers[1]).length; j++) {
    if (item.answers[1][j].parent_answer_id==0) {
        var parent = 1;
    };
    if (parent) {
        k++;
        if (count-1 == j) {
            var last = 1;
        }
        parents.push(
            <View key={j}>
                <View style={styles.answerItem}>

                <View >
                    <Text>
                        {item.answers[1][j].content}
                    </Text>

                </View>


                <View>
                <Text>more reply > </Text>

                </View>

            </View>

        </View>


    );
};
}
```

My sample array is here

```
"answers": [
    [ 5,
        {
            "id": "215",
            "parent_answer_id": "214",
            "question_id": "300",
            "content": "zksjbviul",
            "question_content": "gggg",
            "is_like": "0",
        },
        {
            "id": "214",
            "parent_answer_id": "213",

            "question_id": "300",
            "content": "ksdgzbvjzh,",

            "question_content": "gggg",

        },
        {
            "id": "213",
            "parent_answer_id": "0",
            "question_id": "300",
            "content": "kuqebvjzd",
            "question_content": "gggg",
        },
        {
            "id": "212",
            "parent_answer_id": "0",
            "question_id": "300",
            "content": "iauvhiuds",
            "question_content": "gggg",
        },
        {
            "id": "211",
            "parent_answer_id": "0",
            "question_id": "300",
            "content": "fdfs",
            "question_content": "gggg",
        },

    ]
],
```

Answer (score 1):

1. <s>The first answer is `answers[0][0]`.</s> *Question edited*
2. I'd gather up the "main" answer and related answers before wrangling it into presentation.

That involves recursively finding (and potentially creating) the same tree structure for every child answer; the way your schema is now, every "top level" answer has an arbitrary nested hierarchy of sub-answers, like any threaded conversation mechanism.

Comment: ok my mistake. there were another content on array. Let me update my question.